# Generating $\mathbb R^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Assume that we have $6$ vectors in $\mathbb R^4$ such that every two of them is independent. can we generate $\mathbb R^4$ with them?

Comment: What if all vectors belong to one plane?

Comment: Not necessarily. Image 6 vectors on the 2D plane that are not colinear. Every two are independent, but they span $\mathbb R^2$ only.

Answer (score 8):

No, for example: (1,0,0,0), (1,1,0,0), (1,2,0,0), (1,3,0,0), (1,4,0,0), (1,5,0,0)